# Flag inside a Runnable (Android:Thread inside Service) not updating properly?

Tags: java, android, thread-safety, android-service, runnable

I'm working on a Music Player application using `Service`s. In the Service, I handle all `MediaPlayer` functions in a new thread. This is my class which implements `Runnable`:

```
public class MusicPlayerThread implements Runnable {
    boolean shouldPlayNext=false;

 public void run {
    while(true) {
        if(shouldPlayNext)           //shouldPlayNext always is false
         //code to play next song
     }
 }

 public void playNext() {
    shouldPlayNext=true;            //although control reaches here..
 }
}
```

`playNext()` is a method that is called only from outside this `Thread`.

### So I tried doing this:

```
public void run {
    while(true) {
       if(getshouldPlayNext)       //code to play  next song
    }
}

synchronized public void playNext() {
shouldPlayNext=true;
}

synchronized public boolean getshouldPlayNext() {
return shouldPlayNext;
}
```

Still, the `run` method always sees `shouldPlayNext` to be false. I even tried making declaring the variable as:

`volatile boolean shouldPlayNext=false;`

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: 1. I suggest going over the code once again 2. Are you using the correct object's `playNext()`? 3. Though it shouldn't matter but try adding the volatile keyword in your original code (one without getter and setter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
volatile boolean shouldPlayNext=false;
```

Threads can keep cached copies of variables. So, in theory, a thread can keep working with an old cached copy even when the actual variable is changed. `volatile` keyword make the reads/writes to a variable visible to all threads.

Comment: Yes yes that's exactly what I did. Sorry for the typo in the OP. Doesn't work like I said.